# How to spatially reference data based on the address of the features

Tags: coordinate-system, address

My initial aim was to make a map in ArcMap where the traffic volume of Austria's highway is displayed. I couldn't find any data for that. Instead I found data for Vienna. It is a shp-file that consists of points.
When I added the data to a blank map in ArcMap I get a warning, saying that the data I want to import is missing spatial reference (see in the attachment)[image: warning]

https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/stadt-wien_strassenverkehrszhlung2010wien/resource/4d661e8d-815b-41c7-b6dd-92e0ec1ff2e8

Above you find the link for the data i wanted to import.

How can I make a spatial reference based on the address of the single points?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this metadata](https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/stadt-wien_strassenverkehrszhlung2010wien) page, the bounds are reported in WGS84, but that doesn't necessarily help much since the bounds of the data set may (and in this case, are) in a different coordinate system.

Using [`shpdump(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/shpdump.1.html) I got the coordinates of some of the points in the shapefile and started comparing them with various projection systems. It looks like [MGI Austria GK East](https://epsg.io/31256) (EPSG code 31256). You can either download the PRJ file to include with the shapefile when you load it in ArcMap, or manually tell ArcMap that the coordinates in the shapefile belong to that coordinate system.